# Do linux filesystems retain a count of how many times they have been fsck'd?

Tags: linux, fsck

Do linux filesystems retain a count of how many times they have been fsck'd?

ext2 and ext3 are of particular interest

I have hundreds of systems and I would like to know how many times each filesystem has been:

a) mounted
b) fsck'd
c) modified as a result of an fsck

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ext2 and ext3:
`dumpe2fs /path/to/device` or `tune2fs -l /path/to/device` will show you the mount information.

But no, they only keep track of the number of mounts since the last check.

They do not keep track of fsck-related info.